# Conditional Processing in HTML / JS with Grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm working on an AngularJS app. I'm building this app with Grunt. I have three Grunt tasks: dev, test, and release. I would like to conditionally reference some JavaScript files in each case. For instance, I'd like to do something like this:

**index.html**

```
<!-- if task === 'dev' -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.dev.js"></script>
<!-- else if task === 'test' -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.test.js"></script>
<!-- else -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.min.js"></script>
```

The above is psedocode. Its the idea of conditionally referencing a file at build time with Grunt. In addition, I would like to do something similar in my JavaScript. I would like to do something like:

```
#IF RELEASE
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['service', 'otherModule']);
#ELSE
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['serviceMocks', 'otherModule']);
#ENDIF
```

Once again, the above is pseudocode. I'm in pursuit of the idea of preprocessing my JavaScript with Grunt. Thank you so much!

Comment: See [grunt-targethtml](https://github.com/changer/grunt-targethtml) for the html template. For the javascript files, it depends on how you actually include those files e.g. requirejs, browserify, and plain vanilla script tags. And also how you concat/minify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another option is to use [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace), and only replace Variables:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  replace: {
    dev: {
      options: {
        patterns: [{
          json: {
            "script_src": "/js/script.dev.js",
            "service": "service"
          }
        }]
      },
      files: [{
        expand: true, 
        src: ['index.html', 'your-file.js']
      }]
    },
    test: {
      options: {
        patterns: [{
          json: {
            "script_src": "/js/script.test.js",
            "service": "serviceMock"
          }
        }]
      },
      files: [{
        expand: true, 
        src: ['index.html', 'your-file.js']
      }]
    },
    prod: {
      patterns: [{
          json: {
            "script_src": "/js/script.min.js",
            "service": "service"
          }
      }],
      files: [{
        expand: true, 
        src: ['index.html', 'your-file.js']
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

in your html/js files just prepare the vars, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@@srcipt_src"></script>
```

or

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['@@service', 'otherModule']);
```

if your replacements will get large, you could just put it in some target-specific json files:

```
// e.g. content of dev.json
{
  "script_src": "/js/script.dev.js",
  "service": "service"
}
```

and in your dev-subtask:

```
dev: {
  options: {
    patterns: [{
      json: grunt.file.readJSON('dev.json')
    }],
    files: [{
      expand: true, 
      src: ['index.html', 'your-file.js']
    }]
  }
}
```

this would make sense if your target-specific configurations get large.