# Grunt task that fails if debug code is left

Tags: angular, gruntjs

Is there a grunt task/plugin that could be used to conditionally fail the build if specific patterns are found anywhere in the sources?

I use grunt to build an angular app that uses a data fetching service. To speed up development I run the app locally from nodejs. For debugging purposes I sometimes inject a simulatorService to mock data. When done, the calls should be replaced by the real services again. I would like to catch the human error that someone is not replacing the simulatorService when doing a dist build.

**Update:** Someone asked for code /more details

assume I have a SettingsService making use of a DataService. During debugging I might inject a simService in addition to the real DataService and call it somewhere. Just for quickly trying things out. simService is of course not included in the dist build.

angular.module("myApp")
        .factory("SettingsService", SettingsService);

```
function SettingsService($http, DataService, simService)


DataService.doSomething().then(function(data) { ....}) 
//for trying something I sometimes replace this line by:
simService.doSomething().then(function(data) { ....})
```

When I am done with simulating I remove the simService again. But it's very easy to forget removing the simService from the dependencies of the function call afterwards.

This is not an issue while in development. But if someone does a dist builds, I want a grunt task asserting that "simService" is really removed everywhere.

Comment: Instead of conditionally failing the build - you could utilize two separate tasks in grunt. One for `dev` purposes and one for `build`. Then use [grunt-replace](https://github.com/outaTiME/grunt-replace) to replace a variable  (E.g. `@@Service`)  which is present in your code. See the accepted answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246780/conditional-processing-in-html-js-with-grunt). I'm unsure what the call to your service, _(simulated or real)_, is in terms of code, however  using a variable and replacing it accordingly (`dev` or `build`) may be a better approach.

Comment: I do already have a separate dev build task. The sources of the simulator service are only included in the dev build. But it can still happen that a developer tries to inject the non-existing simulator service somewhere (because he forgot to remove the dependency to it after using). #ifdef - ing would be working, but requires the discipline to add it. If you don't add ifdefs then I still would like the build process to notify me about a left over reference to this service by failing the build step. :)

Comment: Maybe you could include example code in your question/OP that shows how you call/reference both the _simulated_ and _real_ service _(I.e. include examples of the specific patterns you are trying to find)_. I'm assuming it's a reference to an endpoint such as a URL. in which case, instead of hardcoding  the endpoint identifier in the source code include a variable (E.g. `@@ServiceUrl`) instead. The grunt tasks then substitute the variable(s) with the correct identifier accordingly when generating _dev build_ or _dist build_.

Comment: No it's not just an url. Its about mocking behavior. The server side is not under my control (embedded webserver) and sometimes I need a simulator to quickly simulate it's behavior (e.g. authentication responses). I added some example

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with grunt-regex-check:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-regex-check

I added the folloing grunt task running a regexCheck for simService in my sources and fails the build:

```
"regex-check": {
            files: "build/app/**/*.js",
                options: {

                pattern : /simulatorService/g,
                    breakOnError: true
            },
```